# How to fight Targaryen dragons

Tags: mods, crusader-kings-2

I am playing as Illifer Mallister in the 7996 start date. I want to eventually work my way up to King of the Trident (a position currently held by Harren 'the Black' Hoare) and have led a successful league independence war against Harren. The AI Aegon the Conqueror used the Dragon Conquest CB against the Stormlands, and every newly independent lord in the Riverlands.

I am currently watching the Tully's and the Blackwoods and Brackens get their ***** handed to them by the dragons. Is there any hope to avoid swearing fealty? The Stormlands have fallen and half of the Riverlands surrendered without a fight. I have 8000 men including mercernary companies. How can I fight those dragons? Surely others have noticed how overpowered the Targ dragons are in this mod?

Comment: I would be sorely disappointed if Targaryen dragons were not OP. Also, you seem to have never mentioned the name of the mod you're playing.

Comment: @Deltharis http://www.moddb.com/mods/crusader-kings-2-a-game-of-thrones-ck2agot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Crusader Kings. Swear fealty, then plot/marry your way to the top or build up a strong enough alliance and start an independence revolt. Or get your own dragons if you want to spend more time and effort for bonus style points.

Other than that, dragons are obviously supposed to be game changing. There is a duel event in which a character can fight a dragon and wound or slay it, so you might get lucky if you go into battle with strong enough characters. Be prepared for them to die a lot in the process.

Comment: I am already knee-deep in debt to the Iron Bank of Braavos paying for my mercs. Interestingly enough, my son got some good random traits at game start up and killed Balerion. Unfortunately Queen Visenya was in the mood to immediately re-declare war and castrate him after he was captured a week later. Then I got greyscale. I swear, the Riverlands and all those who aspire to rule them are cursed!

Answer (score 1):

You could also employ a lot of mercenaries, but it demands a lot of money to hire and maintain them.

I don't remember how strong Aegon's dragons were when I played in that starting date, but when I fought against Daenerys Targaryen as the Free City of Tyrosh, Drogon had at least 30+ attack, while Viserion and Rhaegal had 20+ which demanded my army to be twice the size of hers, so you should expect to need at least 3x to 4x Aegon's army size.

Also, when engaging her army, I always tried to split them up and lure them apart. Boats are great to do it, specially if you are marching in your own territory, seem that you can embark and disembark quickly.

You could also cheat, adding some gold to your treasury, by pressing alt+21 and then typing "cash #" (where # represents the amount of gold you want) and try to pay it back later as a personal challenge, but it might take the fun out of the game of thrones after all.